# Getting a ? at the end of a file name after writing to it in c (eg. writtenTo.txt?)

Tags: c, file-io

So my first assignment for my OS course is to read a file byte by byte in c then write the result to a new file. I have to take the directory for both the input and output files. I'm getting a really strange result after I run this. The file is created and the text is written to it. However, the file appears with the name writtenTo.txt? and the file type is simply Document (I'm on a mac running yosemite). To read the file I have to open it with vim.

EDIT: Updated my code to working code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    char * fileText;
    FILE * inFile;
    FILE * outFile;
    // /Users/admin/Documents/School/2014-2015/cs350/sample.txt
    char inFilePath[256];
    char outFilePath[256];
    printf("%s", "Input the directory to the input file:\n");
    fgets(inFilePath, sizeof(inFilePath), stdin);
    printf("%s", "Input the directory to the output file:\n");
    fgets(outFilePath, sizeof(outFilePath), stdin);


    for (int i =0; i < sizeof(inFilePath)/sizeof(char); i++){
        if (inFilePath[i] == '\n'){
            inFilePath[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        if (inFilePath[i] == '\r') {
            inFilePath[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i =0; i < sizeof(outFilePath)/sizeof(char); i++){
        if (outFilePath[i] == '\n'){
            outFilePath[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        if (outFilePath[i] == '\r'){
             outFilePath[i] = '\0';
             break;
        }
    }


    size_t len;
    inFile = fopen(inFilePath, "r");


    fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(inFile);
    rewind(inFile);

    fileText = (char *) malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    fread(fileText, sizeof(char), len, inFile);
    fileText[len] = '\0';
    fclose(inFile);

    outFile = fopen(outFilePath,"w");
    //fprintf(outFile, "%s", fileText);
    fwrite(fileText, sizeof(char), len, outFile);
    fclose(outFile);
    free(fileText);
    return 0;



}
```

Comment: for (int i =0; i < sizeof(outFilePath)/sizeof(char); i++){
    if (inFilePath[i] == '\n') inFilePath[i] = '\0';
} replace inFilePath with outFilePath

Comment: Also your comments, user prompts and question text regarding the file names are misleading. The user's input is not interpreted as a directory name but as a (absolute or relative) path to a file, directly suitable for an fopen call.

Comment: @PeterSchneider relative paths are allowed. They just use the working directory as the relative root.

Comment: In the loops, once you set a character to NULL (`\0`), there's no point processing the rest of the string. Add a `break;` statement after the assignment (BE SURE TO USE BRACES TO WRAP THE STATEMENTS)

Comment: @ColeJohnson True; I was not arguing against how the input is used but how the user is prompted. I would input a directory name, which would be wrong.

Comment: @PeterSchneider oh, I see what you mean

Comment: Thanks Peter I will update the phrasing. Cole I'll add the break as well.

Comment: Ah, and then there is the sizeof(char) which seems to enjoy a new popularity after all these years ;-). sizeof(char) is always and by definition 1, independent of the number of bits in a char. It also is the unit of the `sizeof()` result. Dividing by it is not wrong but still betrays a deplorable lack of standard memorization.

Comment: I was always taught to use as little actual numbers in my code as possible and rely on variables and functions if I can. That's why i use sizeof(char).

Comment: Whoever taught you that was right. Good principle. Adhere to it. But the solution here is not to replace sizeof(char) by 1, but instead to *omit* it. 1 is the neutral element of division and multiplication. If you want to iterate through an array by character, `sizeof(array)` is the right number. Just like that.

Comment: regarding calls to fgets() 1) after each call, replace the trailing '\n' with  '\0' (which is where the '?' is coming from. 2) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   The same returned value checking should always be performed for fopen,, malloc, fread, ftell, fseek, rewind to assure the operation was successful

Comment: I do replace the trailing \n. What should the values be for fgets?

Answer (score 4):

When you write the data back, you make an implicit assumption that the file does not have embedded null characters. The problem with the trailing `?` is that you failed to null-terminate the string that you read into `fileText`, which is uninitialized. `fprintf` reads past the end of the buffer, and produces a "junk" character at the end of the file.

You have allocated an extra `char` for `'\0'`, so what's missing is simply an assignment of null character to the last `char` of the buffer:

```
fread(fileText, sizeof(char), len, inFile);
fileText[len] = '\0'; // <<== Add this
```

A better approach would be to use `fwrite` in place of `fprintf` for the output. This would solve the problem of embedded null characters, and prevent reading past the end of the buffer:

```
fwrite(fileText, sizeof(char), len, outFile);
fclose(outFile);
free(fileText); // <<== Don't forget to free the buffer
```

Comment: Did you mean fileText[len] = '\0'? I tried that as well as correcting my loop to remove the newline character. I'll try fwrite when I'm in front of my computer again.

Comment: @DustySack Yes, I copied a wrong identifier. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

fgets reads a line *including* the newline which thus becomes a part of the file name. That's possible on Unixes but not printable. Oh, and then @user312023 observed correctly why your attempt to replace the newline in outfile fails ;-).
Update: @Basile had another word of caution regarding Mac OS (not sure it applies on OSX, and iirc on a Mac the EOL sequence would be \n\r (as opposed to MS's \r\n), which would make your algorithm valid for Mac once your copy/paste error regarding the input buffers is fixed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, saw that comment, too and fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Very probably (at least on Linux), [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) is getting a end-of-line terminated line. On your MacOSX OS, I guess that the end of line might be two characters (e.g. `\r` & `\n`). You are removing only one. The other remains and is becoming part of the file name.

I would instead read a file path without any spaces (perhaps using [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)). BTW, the file paths could be the program arguments (given to `int main(int argc, char**argv)`....)

Comment: Part of the assignment was reading it as an input not from program arguments (which is how I would have done it given the choice). I'm not very familiar with c so making this program involved a lot of googling.